# Как удалить конечный слеш?

Tags: php, .htaccess, битрикс

Приветствую!

Имеем, скажем, такую структуру сайта на **Bitrix**:

```
<a href="http://site.ru/poezda">Поезда</a>
  <a href="http://site.ru/poezda/poezd1">Поезд 1</a>
  <a href="http://site.ru/poezda/poezd2">Поезд 2</a>
<a href="http://site.ru/kontakty">Контакты</a>

<!-- В конце ссылок нет слешей -->
```

При переходе по первой (Поезда) или последней (Контакты) ссылкам в конец адресной строки добавляется слеш, т.е. получается `http://site.ru/poezda/` или `http://site.ru/kontakty/` соответственно.
<s>Я так понимаю это происходит из-за того, что это "Разделы" (Папки, которые содержат файлы `.section.php` и `index.php`)</s>

Подскажите пожалуйста, как избавиться от этих слешей в конце?

**P.S.** Файл `.htaccess` стандартный, содержит эти строки для роутинга:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

---

**UPD**:

при добавлении правила в urlwrite.php ничего не поменялось :(

```
$arUrlRewrite = array(
  array(
    "CONDITION" => "#^/poezda#",
    "PATH" => "/poezda/index.php",
  )
);
```

в `CONDITION` пробовал указывать различные вариации, такие как `#^/poezda#`, `#^/poezda`, `/poezda` и пр.

---

**UPD 2**

При попытке добавить файл (а не раздел) и описать правило - слеш всё равно добавился в конце. Как побороть это правило?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `mod_dir` добавляем:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

В `mod_rewrite` добавляем:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

В Битриксе для управления путями есть (как видно из .htaccess) файл /bitrix/urlrewrite.php, но вот в чем загвоздка, одно дело вы хотите создать маршруты которых нет (виртуальные) и тогда отсутствие слеша обосновано, но когда вы реальной директории пытаетесь его убрать тут возникает вопрос, зачем ?

Comment: желание заказчика :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
```

Если проблема в обработке - то добавить возможный слеш в правила Rewrite

Если в эстетике - правка urlrewrite.php

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]` - не помогло. Можно поподробней про эстетику, пожалуйста?

Comment: вроде разобрался, но не помогло. Обновил вопрос, есть идеи? =\